# Split JSON into multiple files

Tags: json, shell, awk, jq

I have json file exported from mongodb which looks like:

```
{"_id":"99919","city":"THORNE BAY"}
{"_id":"99921","city":"CRAIG"}
{"_id":"99922","city":"HYDABURG"}
{"_id":"99923","city":"HYDER"}
```

there are about 30000 lines, I want to split each line into it's own `.json` file. *(I'm trying to transfer my data onto couchbase cluster)*

I tried doing this:

```
cat cities.json | jq -c -M '.' | \
while read line; do echo $line > .chunks/cities_$(date +%s%N).json; done
```

but I found that it seems to drop loads of line and the output of running this command only gave me 50 odd files when I was expecting 30000 odd!!

Is there a logical way to make this not drop any data using anything that would suite?

Comment: BSD `date` doesn't support `%N` as a fraction of a second. You are losing lines because you are only generating a unique output file name once per second, and you are processing far more than one line per second.

Comment: Convertcsv.com has a tool to split CSV, text, or JSON Lines/ND files, see: https://www.convertcsv.com/text-split.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about the exact filenames, if you want to split input into multiple files, just use [`split`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html).

```
jq -c . < cities.json | split -l 1 --additional-suffix=.json - .chunks/cities_
```

Comment: doesn't quite work I'm getting `split: illegal option -- -` :(

Comment: worked it out for osx you need to install coreutils: `brew install coreutils`. Then use `gsplit` instead of `split` :)

Comment: If you *really* don't care about the output file names, `gsplit` is only necessary for the `--additional-suffix` option.

Answer (score 1):

In general to split any text file into separate files per-line using any awk on any UNIX system is simply:

```
awk '{close(f); f=".chunks/cities_"NR".json"; print > f}' cities.json
```